# Братско - Усть-Илимский или Братско-Усть-Илимский?

Tags: дефис

Скажите, как правильно: Братско - Усть-Илимский промышленный комплекс или Братско-Усть-Илимский? Где вообще можно почитать про написание таких прилагательных?

Answer (score 2):

Это сложное прилагательное, образованное от основ, обозначающих равноправные понятия; между частями таких прилагательных в их начальной форме можно вставить сочинительный союз, значит, пишется через дефис: Братско-Усть-Илимский (Братский и Усть-Илимский)
Этот принцип написания распространяется и на прилагательные, состоящие из нескольких основ: кузнечно-слесарно-механический цех, префиксально-суффиксально-постфиксальные глаголы, белково-витаминно-минеральные добавки(Б.Букчина.Л.Калакуцкая.Сложные слова.-М., «Наука», 1977)

Тире с отбивкой ставится между существительными, означающими участников каких-либо организаций, мероприятий и т. д., если после них идет зависимое слово, например Государства – Члены ООН, страны – участницы договора Но при отсутствии зависимого слова  ставится дефис: страны-участницы, компании-экспоненты. Инженер-электромеханик (по флоту)- дефис между двумя нарицательными сущ., объединящий их в одно понятие, но: инженер - электромеханик по флоту(тире обосабливает приложение)Или между словами, обозначающими пределы(временные, пространственные). 
 Тире прибитое ставится между собственными именами, совокупностью которых устойчиво называется  какой-либо закон, уравнение и т. д., например: код Рида–Соломона,
алфавит Рида–Мюллера .

http://rudocs.exdat.com/docs/index-21993.html?page=6

Answer (score 0):

Не сталкивался напрямую, но по двум соображениям написал бы через тире.
Соображения такие. Первое. Использование двух дефисов в одном слове не рекомендуется. Раньше было даже на уровне запрета, сейчас, несколько смягчили. Второе. Дефисы, если их всё-таки использовать здесь, несут разный смысл, что зрительно нехорошо.
Что до использования тире вместо дефиса, то можно сослаться на аналогию. Подобным образом оформляются конструкции, требующие по общим правилам дефиса, но содержащие более одного слова в какой-либо части, например: "Генерал-майор -- инженер".

Так что я за "Братско - Усть-Илимский".

//-----------

Для неверующих в замену дефиса на тире:

> > Вопрос № 242905
> > Как правильно, через тире или дефис пишется выражение инженер - электромеханик по флоту. Разгорелся спор, и никак не можем прийти к единому мнению.
> > pero 
> > Ответ справочной службы русского языка
> > Может ставиться дефис, если слова "по флоту" в равной мере относятся и к инженеру, и к электромеханику. Если же эти слова относятся только к электромеханику, *то вместо дефиса ставится тире с пробелами*.

Справка на грамоте
(курсив мой - b-s).

Comment: Тире-знак препинания. Дефис оформляет полуслитное написание слов.

Comment: >Тире-знак препинания. Дефис оформляет полуслитное написание слов.Тире-знак препинания. Дефис оформляет полуслитное написание слов.  
  
Волга впадает в Каспийское море. Пятью пять - двадцать пять. У кошки четыре ноги. Алене нечего возразить, поэтому она говорит банальности. 

Больше тут комментировать нечего.

Comment: Т.е. Вы хотите сказать, что тире в данном случае нужно отбивать пробелами?

Comment: Слово "нужно" я не употреблял. Это предложение в порядке обсуждения, как Вы можете легко заметить. И звучит оно как "заменить дефис на тире по аналогии с названными случаями".
 
А тире отбивается пробелами всегда, кроме неуоторых специальных случаев.